# Sorry first time coding! javaScript function findMyCampsites issue with my else if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

[This is the output error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5FB8.png)

structure for campground variable is below-->

> let campgrounds = [
>
> { number: 1, view: "ocean", partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
>
> { number: 5, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
>
> { number: 12, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
>
> { number: 18, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
>
> { number: 23, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
>
> ];

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds,view,partySize){
  let siteNumbers=[];
    for (let i=0;i<campgrounds.length;i++){
      if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false && campgrounds[i].view===view && campgrounds[i].partySize>=partySize)
        siteNumbers.push(campgrounds[i].number);       
 
else if (campgrounds[i].isReserved!==false && campgrounds[i].view!== view && campgrounds[i].partySize !== partySize)
 "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";  }           
    return siteNumbers;  
      findMyCampsites(campgrounds,"ocean",4,8);
       findMyCampsites(campgrounds,"forest",4);  }
```

Every line of code throughout this sequence is executing properly EXCEPT the lines containing
The issue here is that my "else if" statement is not returning the string after it completes the "for loop", I am getting a return appearing as "[]" rather than my string.

```
else if (campgrounds[i].isReserved!==false && campgrounds[i].view!== view && campgrounds[i].partySize !== partySize)
 "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";  }
```

If somebody has an idea what I am missing here please feel free to comment thoughts and ideas. Thank you.

Comment: *"The issue here is that my "else if" statement is not returning the string [...]"* because you're not `return`ing the string. Would be a lot easier spotting issues if you would properly format your code though.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read, friend. It might be worth breaking the conditional into multiple lines and not using the oneline conditional, wrapping explicitly in brackets. It looks like your else-if statement just has the string without it assigning to anything or returning anywhere.

Comment: I added that into the code and it ended up cancelling out my "return siteNumber;" command as well as still not returning the string.

Comment: I also tried the multi-line format you two have described and my program would not accept it unless I used condensed format, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be wrong before the readability issue.

```
     if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false && campgrounds[i].view===view && campgrounds[i].partySize>=partySize)
        siteNumbers.push(campgrounds[i].number);       
else if (campgrounds[i].isReserved!==false && campgrounds[i].view!== view && campgrounds[i].partySize !== partySize)
```

will be..

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let siteNumbers = []
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false && campgrounds[i].view === view && campgrounds[i].partySize >= partySize)
      siteNumbers.push(campgrounds[i].number)
  }
  if(siteNumbers.length > 0){
    return siteNumbers
  }else{
    return 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'
  }
```

I hope this code is what you want

Answer (score 0):

1. At the moment your code is *either* adding the site to the array if it's available, or, well, `"Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party"` *just on its own* should give you an error.
2. The second point is that you appear to be calling your function from *within* the function.

Here's a rewritten example of what I think you were hoping to achieve.

1. It assigns `campgrounds[i]` to `cg` to make the code a little easier to read.
2. It iterates over the whole array first. If a site is `reserved` it skips to the next object (as you don't need to check the rest of the condition), otherwise if it finds a match it adds that site number to the array.
3. It returns *either* a) the site array if it's not empty *or* b) a message that says there are no available sites.

```js
const campgrounds=[{number:1,view:"ocean",partySize:8,isReserved:true},{number:5,view:"ocean",partySize:4,isReserved:false},{number:12,view:"ocean",partySize:4,isReserved:true},{number:18,view:"forest",partySize:4,isReserved:false},{number:23,view:"forest",partySize:4,isReserved:true}];

function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  
  const siteNumbers = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    
    // Make things a little more readable by assigning
    // `campgrounds[i]` to a variable
    const cg = campgrounds[i];
    
    // If the site is reserved we don't need to
    // bother checking anything else, and can
    // continue to the next object
    if (cg.isReserved) continue;
    
    // However if the site matches the
    // rest of the condition add it to the array
    if (cg.view === view && cg.partySize >= partySize) {
      siteNumbers.push(cg.number);
    }

  }
  
  // Once the loop is complete return either the array
  // if the array is not empty...
  if (siteNumbers.length) return siteNumbers;
  
  // ...or the "error" message
  return 'No available sites';

}

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 38));
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'forest', 4));
```

Comment: Thank you this really cleared things up for me.